# congruent matrices and eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $Y$ be diaogalizable matrix $Y = PDP^\top$, where $P$ is orthogonal and $X$ be congruent to $Y$, that is there exists an invertible matrix $A$ such that $X=A^\top YA$. Thus we can find a linearly independent basis in which $X$ is a diagonal matrix, namely $X = (P^\top A)^\top D(P^\top A)$. Now if I want to find a lower bound estimate of the minimum eigen-value of $X$ in terms of $D$ how can I proceed?

My solution:
$$\sigma_\min(X) = \frac{1}{\|X^{-1}\|}$$
$$\|X^{-1}\| \leq \|P\|^2\|A^{-1}\|^2\|D^{-1}\|=\|A^{-1}\|^2\|D^{-1}\|$$
Therefore,
$\sigma_\min(X) =\frac{1}{\|X^{-1}\|} \geq \sigma_\min(A)^2\sigma_\min(D)$

Comment: you are describing symmetric matrices; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia

Comment: Not really, Not interested in the qualification, rather an estimate of the exact lower bound

Comment: Just wondering if my calculations are correct